# What's the difference between driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click", button) and JS button.click() in console?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm collecting some public data via Python3 / selenium 3.141.0 / chromedriver / chromium 91

The site in question is: https://publicindex.sccourts.org/Lexington/PublicIndex/PISearch.aspx

My selenium clicks are being detected on the search button, and on the links in the search results.

I've tried the basics without success:

```
button.click()

action.click(button).perform()
```

What I find to be interesting, is popping open the console and performing a JS `button.click()` - works every time.

However, `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click", button)`, which I'd expect to be equivalent, does not.

Why not?, What's the difference here? Questions I've found in searching only discuss the difference between a JS click and webdriver click.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you posted is literally your code, then it looks like `"arguments[0].click"` should be `"arguments[0].click()"`. You need to actually *call* click(), not just reference its name.

Comment: My apologies, what a terrible place for an inaccuracy - it really muddies the waters. It was late when I posted this question and I don't see how to edit it. I am using "arguments[0].click()" in the actual code. This "works" in the sense that the click is registered, but it's detected as automation where as using JS in the console is not.